# Why does Emacs not pick up all of my Mac OSX keyboard layout?

Tags: osx, keyboard-layout

I'm using the custom keyboard layout found at https://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/macosx.html.

When I use Emacs in gui mode, most keys are fine, but the 10-keys -- which the layout redefines like a telephone keypad -- are not remapped. That is, they give the number written on the key and not the remapped one.

I'm curious: how is it even possible for Emacs to see keys differently from every other application?

### Update

Another example, emacs binds cmd-left and cmd-right to switch between frames. It also ignores my settings in macos Settings which are usually cmd-` but I have them on cmd-$ for Move Focus Next Window. How can emacs override the system-wide keys?

Comment: I don't understand why Emacs would be different from other applications. I ended up using Karabiner, which comes with an “EventViewer” application, to see what my external keyboard numpad was sending, and I used Karabiner to remap them to the keys I wanted (e.g. `<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEYPAD_8, KeyCode::CURSOR_UP</autogen>`).